# How can I do implicit differentiation in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the equation `y*x + Sqrt[x^2 + 4*y] == 2`. I need to calculate $dx/dy$ in $x=0$, $dx/dy$ in $y=1$, and also the tangent to that curve in $(0, 1)$

How do I do implicit differentiation? I've tried to do it the same way as normal differentiation but it doesn't work.

Comment: There is a search feature [that can help find answers to such questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcalculus-and-analysis%5D+implicit+differentiation).

Answer (score 2):

```
eq = y x + Sqrt[x^2 + 4 y] == 2
```

Calculate: $dy/dx$

```
funcX = Dt[eq, x]
(* y + x Dt[y, x] + (2 x + 4 Dt[y, x])/(2 Sqrt[x^2 + 4 y]) == 0 *)
solX = Solve[funcX, Dt[y, x]]
(* {{Dt[y, x] -> (-x - y Sqrt[x^2 + 4 y])/(2 + x Sqrt[x^2 + 4 y])}}  *)
```

Calculate: $dx/dy$

```
funcY = Dt[eq, y]
(* x + y Dt[x, y] + (4 + 2 x Dt[x, y])/(2 Sqrt[x^2 + 4 y]) == 0 *)
solY = Solve[funcY, Dt[x, y]]
(* {{Dt[x, y] -> (-2 - x Sqrt[x^2 + 4 y])/(x + y Sqrt[x^2 + 4 y])}} *)
```

The equation of the [tangent line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_curve#Tangent_and_normal_vector) at a regular point.

```
tangentcurve = (Dt[y, x] /. solX[[1]] /. x -> 0 /. y -> 1) (x - 
0) + (Dt[x, y] /. solY[[1]] /. x -> 0 /. y -> 1) (y - 1) == 0

(* 1 - x - y == 0 *)

ContourPlot[Evaluate[{tangentcurve, eq}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{0, 1}]}, Axes -> True, 
Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Solve by  normal differentiation:

```
EQx = y[x]*x + Sqrt[x^2 + 4 y[x]] == 2;
EQy = y*x[y] + Sqrt[x[y]^2 + 4  y] == 2;
SolX = Solve[D[EQx, x], y'[x]]
SolY = Solve[D[EQy, y], x'[y]]
TangentCurve = (y'[x] /. SolX[[1]] /. y[x] -> y /. x -> 0 /. 
y -> 1) (x - 0) + (x'[y] /. SolY[[1]] /. x[y] -> x /. x -> 0 /. 
y -> 1) (y - 1) == 0
ContourPlot[Evaluate[{TangentCurve, (EQx /. y[x] -> y)}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{0, 1}]}, Axes -> True, 
Frame -> False]
```

Comment: Do you agree it's a duplicate of the question I linked above?

Comment: @MichaelE2. If  got from you `upvote`  then I will agree with you.

Comment: Why don't you answer the other question, then?

Answer (score 0):

```
(Dt[x, y] /. 
   First@Solve[Dt[y x + Sqrt[x^2 + 4 y] == 2, y], Dt[x, y]])
     /. {x -> 0, y -> 1}
```

`Dt` allows the taking of total derivatives. Using its second argument we can essentially take the total derivative with respect to `y` specifically, and then solve for the specific term `Dt[x,y]` which will remain, which is equivalent to $dx/dy$ in this case. Then we can substitute in `{x -> 0, y -> 1}` to get the result. You will want to change this substitution to get the other values you're interested in.

This agrees with direct differentiation:

```
xval = x /. Solve[y x + Sqrt[x^2 + 4 y] == 2, x];
Limit[D[xval, y], y -> 1]
```

Where one of the values is indeterminate because it refers to the wrong branch, but the other value is equivalent to the one acquired by implicit differentiation above.